# SQL 2 tables sum in one

Tags: mysql, sql, function, group-by, sum

Hello i have a bit of a problem. I'm trying to write down SQL query.
I have tried many things but i could't find how to add few rows together and add few data from another table if there is more then one thing you have to group by.

Here is the data when i use my select the basic one with order by etc.

Tabel No.1

```
 Got      User_ID    Month
 100      1          1
 200      1          1
 500      1          2
 400      1          2
 50       1          3
 50       2          1
 150      2          1
 200      2          1
 100      2          2
 20       2          3
```

Table No. 2

```
 Spend    User_ID    Month
 50       1          1
 20       1          1
 50       1          2
 100      2          1
 50       2          2
 50       2          2
 50       2          3
```

And with SQL query i want to get this table Total = Got - spend

```
 User_ID    Month   GOT    Spend    Total
 1          1       300    70       230
 1          2       900    50       850
 1          3       50     0        50
 2          1       400    100      300
 2          2       100    100      0
 2          3       20     50       -30
```

Is there a way i could get it?

I have fiddle aready made:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cda13f/1/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/712f0d/5)

You can do it like below :

```
select NO1.User_Id, NO1.Month, sum(NO1.Got) as Got, 
coalesce(Spend, 0) Spend, (sum(NO1.Got) - coalesce(Spend, 0)) Total
from NO1
left join (select User_Id, Month, sum(Spend) as Spend from NO2
          group by User_Id, Month) NO2 on NO1.User_Id=NO2.User_Id and NO1.Month=NO2.Month
group by NO1.User_Id, NO1.Month, Spend
order by NO1.User_Id, NO1.Month;
```

Comment: Will try and i will let you know if i was successful

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can also check it easily in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/712f0d/5)

Comment: I will! still doing things. Because this is jsut like demo and i have a bit more compex  things to do in database haha :)

Comment: Sir! would you mind helping me with the same exact query just with other data, i would like to know why it doenst count spend: here is the fiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e76ef9/21

Comment: Sorry i am on weekend leave, i can try helping you on Monday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161358/discussion-between-imantas-balandis-and-md-suman-kabir).

Comment: The answer I provided based on the given scenario which works. If you are facing trouble on implementing it in real/different scenario, you should post a new question describing well your current issues, you can also give reference to this post. I hope you will get help from others. If you still didn't get solution, i will try to help you on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join two aggregate queries:

```
select t1.User_Id, t1.Month, 
       IFNULL(t1.Got_Total, 0) As Got, 
       IFNULL(t2.Spend_Total, 0) As Spend, 
       IFNULL(t1.Got_Total, 0) - IFNULL(t2.Spend_TOTAL, 0) As Total
from
  (select User_Id, Month, sum(Got) as Got_TOTAL
   from NO1
   group by User_Id, Month) t1
left join 
  (select User_Id, Month, sum(Spend) as Spend_TOTAL
   from NO2
   group by User_Id, Month) t2
on t1.User_Id = t2.User_Id and t1.Month = t2.Month
order by t1.User_Id, t1.Month
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/712f0d/11/0)

Comment: I think you sql does not give row if spend is  =0

Comment: That's a data issue. Your fiddle which I borrowed from did not have Spend = 100 for ID =2 and Month = 2 but had 50 instead and hence the -50 result. Simply change and the 100 - 100 = 0 line should appear. I updated fiddle.

Comment: It is about ID 1 month 3

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` with `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` wrappers.